# How to move a NSObject to a Point(x,y)?

Tags: iphone, sprite

I have a Sprite object defined as follows:

```
@interface Sprite : NSObject {
CGFloat x;                      // x location
CGFloat y;                      // y location
CGFloat r;                      // red tint
CGFloat g;                      // green tint
CGFloat b;                      // blue tint
CGFloat alpha;                  // alpha value, for transparency
}
```

In the `initWithCoder` function of the containing view i instanciated it using:

```
sprite = [[Sprite alloc] init];
sprite.x = 50; 
sprite.y = 100; 
sprite.width = 100; 
sprite.height = 200; 
sprite.r = 0.0; 
sprite.g = 1.0; 
sprite.b = 0.0;
```

and I correctly see a green rectangle.
Now I would like to move it. I defined a moveTo method like this

```
- (void) moveTo: (CGPoint) p
{
    x = p.x;
    y = p.y;
}
```

But when I call it nothing happens. I don't know how to redraw my object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSObject aren't drawable objects. If you want to have a drawable object you should use UIView or its subclass that have all methods for drawing itself like drawRect

Answer (score 4):

How do you see a green rect? where do you draw it? NSObject cannot draw...

You could derive it from a UIView and change your moveTo to be like this:

```
- (void) moveTo: (CGPoint) p
{
   self.frame.origin = p;
   [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```